# Pegando valor de uma coluna oculta da datatables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Como faço para pegar o valor de uma coluna que esta com o `visible: false`?

```
 "columns": [
                    { data: "Nomes", autoWidth: true, visible: false},   
            ]
```

Exemplo da coluna Nomes, atualmente estou fazendo assim.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(0).text()
```

Só que se eu fazer desse jeito ele não retorna se a coluna estiver com `visible: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando o Datatables é renderizado, as colunas invisíveis são excluídas totalmente do DOM, portanto sendo inacessíveis via JavaScript comum. É preciso usar a API do componente, ou seja, o método [row().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) irá retornar os dados da linha via JSON.

Para pegar a linha do elemento clicado você usa:

```
var linha = $(this).closest("tr");
```

O `.closest("tr")` irá buscar o primeiro elemento `tr` pai do elemento clicado.

Como a coluna é nomeada com o termo `Nomes`, basta pegar o valor de `.data().Nomes` da row retornada na variável `linha`:

```
var texto = $('#table_id').DataTable().row(linha).data().Nomes;
```

> O seletor `'#table_id'` é o id da tabela. Altere para o id da sua
>   tabela atual.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#table_id').DataTable({
      "columns": [
         { data: "Nomes", autoWidth: true, visible: false}, null, null
      ]       
   });

   $(".btn").click(function(){
      var linha = $(this).closest("tr");
      var texto = $('#table_id').DataTable().row(linha).data().Nomes;
      console.log(texto);
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1 invisível</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td><button class="btn">clique</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1 invisível</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td><button class="btn">clique</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```